# Combining 2 files to create 1 file as output

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I got 2 documents which look likes:
First:

```
port2
port4
port10
etc.
```

Second:

```
port1
some stuff
about the port
I do not need
!
port2
some stuff
about the port
I really need
!
some generic stuff which is completely useless
!
port3
some stuff
about the port
I do not need
!
port4
some stuff
about the port
I really need
!
etc
```

Now, what I want is to create a loop that for each line in the first document we'll go through the second document and create a new file which contains all the data I need ("port2" until "!", "port4" until "!" etc)

What I got so far:

```
def access():
with open ("D:/portlist.txt") as f1, open ("D:/config.txt") as f2:
    match = False
    for line in f1:
        newConfig = open ("D:/portconfig.test.txt", "a")
        interface = line
        for line2 in f2:
            if re.match(interface, line2):
                newConfig.write(line2)
                print(line2)
                match = True
            elif re.match("!", line2):
                match = False   
            elif match:
                newConfig.write(line2)
        newConfig.close()   
access()
```

Problem is that the script stops after returning all about port2. It seems like the script doesn't return to the first loop to continue the process.
Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would help us greatly if you showed us the desired output file from those two example input files. Otherwise, your question is pretty good. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem stems from the fact that once a file is read to the end, it doesn't automatically seek back to the first point. Since you're looping over the second file for each of the values you search, you either need to seek back via `f2.seek(0)`, or simply read the file's content in memory only once and then loop on that.

About your code a quick (and dirty) solution exploits the fact that you have block separators (`!`):

```
with open(...) as f1, open(...) as f2:
  section_names_to_keep = f1.read().splitlines()
  config_content = f2.read()

config_blocks = config_content.split('!\n')
blocks_to_keep = [ bl for bl in config_blocks if bl.splitlines()[0] in section_names_t_keep ]

with open('your_output_file.txt', 'a') as fp:
  fp.write('!\n'.join(blocks_to_keep))
```

**Note:** You weren't too clear on the expected output format, so I assume it should look like `config.txt`. I write to the output file all at once (first I generate the output content in memory with `'!\n'.join(blocks_to_keep)` and then it gets written out). If (as I'm assuming) your data is small, this won't be an issue. If that's not the case, just loop over `blocks_to_keep` and write out block by block.

#### Small code explanation:

In the first block I simply load the content of both files. Since for the first file we're interested in each line, I already split it over the lines.

In the second block, I split the config over the block separator `!\n` and then I filter the list of blocks keeping only those blocks whose first line is in the list we got from the first file.

The third block is just output.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid this gives me an "IndexError: list index out of range". Although I understand the error, I cannot find the issue...

Comment: I'd guess it's coming from the `[0]` after `splitlines()`, is it possible that you have an empty block in your config? Can't say much more with the information given in the question

Comment: That's what I believe as well. f1 just sums up the port (e.g. port1, port 5, port7) each on a different line. f2 begins with the "begin" en ends with "end". Between the blocks of data there is a "!", or multiple !'s (can this be the cause?). No white lines at all.

Comment: the multiple !'s was  the issue. I will rewrite some of the code to generate the txt to avoid those. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant by empty block :)